# Exposing IIS on Web

Tags: iis, hosting

I have:

1. Internet with dynamic IP address
2. Windows 8

Can I expose my web application hosted on IIS to anyone on the web - 
by IP address or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps are as follows:

1. Manually configure an IP address for your machine (guide [here](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-553.html))
2. Set up port forwarding in your router for Port 80 (http) or Port 443 (https) to your newly configured manually configured IP address
3. Confirm that your IIS configuration has binding to Port 80 or Port 443 without an IP address filter: `bindingInformation=":80"`. If you're wanting to use HTTPS, make sure your certificates are correctly configured and you're listening on port 443. [HTTPS configuration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324069)
4. Register with a DynamicDNS service such as [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/) or [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/), or request a static IP address from your ISP. You can then use your new Dynamic DNS address, or static IP address, on port 80 or 443 from outside of your network.

Of course, you may need to configure firewalls, both on your machine and potentially on your router, as well as correctly configuring IIS. It varies a lot from system to system, but these are the bare minimum steps you'll need.